# JavaScript подключение к серверу

Tags: javascript

Мне известен метод XMLHttpRequest.
Дело в том, что он общается с сервером на протоколе http.
Мне же нужно отправлять и получать запросы/ответы в произвольной форме.

Чтобы было понятнее: 
Для курсовой работы я пишу определенную программу на php. Так же, мне требуется на том же php написать сервер. С этим проблем нет.
А так же стоит задача о собственном протоколе этой программы.

Из-за того, что клиентской средой необходимо сделать браузер (благо его хоть писать не надо. Или надо?) Встает вопрос, а можно ли на js общаться с сервером с помощью произвольного протокола, и если можно, то каким образом?

Заранее спасибо за ответы, знатоки.

Comment: Насколько знаю возможности использовать свой протокол нету, а чем не устраивают стандартные протоколы?

Comment: Да в принципе полностью устраивают, просто хочется "поразить" комиссию.

Comment: Запхнуть произвольный протокол в WebSocket не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи по сути вариантов то и нет. Вам необходимо смотреть в сторону [**websocket**](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets). Передавать сможете в произвольном виде любые данные хоть текст, хоть бинарные. Для php (да и любого другого языка) без проблем найдете уже готовые реализации и примеры websocket-сервера. Для пробы пера и тестов можно первоначально обойтись без сервера и использовать тестовые эхо-сервера ([типа такого](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)).

Comment: Да, это интересно, но дело в том, что websocket протокол... может я плохо понимаю теорию, но мне требуется разработать собственный протокол поверх tcp, чем websocket уже является. Или это из разряда "миссия невыполнима"?

Comment: @RostD Если именно из браузера, то думаю будет именно из разряда "миссия невыполнима". Здесь затрагиваются вопросы безопасности. И изначально тот же websocket принимался вштыки по этой причине. Временно, когда находились дыры в протоколе, от него некоторые отказывались.